# Need to implement FirestorePagingAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, adapter

I am trying to implement FirestorePagingAdapter to this adapter to implement pagination, but it is then giving me several errors. I using filters for the recyclerview class as well. Below is the code I am using. For the past few days I am trying  to implement FirestorePagingAdapter, but not able to do so, it is giving various errors which I am not able to resolve. Please assist me to resolve this issue.

I am using firestore database for my backend. If any more information is required please let me know.

I have tried to shorten the code as much as I can. If try to shorten it more, it may not give the Clear idea what needs to be done.

PostAdapter2

```
   public class PostAdapter2 extends FirestoreAdapter<PostAdapter2.ViewHolder> {


        private PostsAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener;
        private View.OnClickListener buttonListener;
        private Context mContext;
        private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private String mUserId;
        private Query mQuery;
        private ListenerRegistration mRegistration;


        private ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot> mSnapshots = new ArrayList<>();


        private String id;


        private static final String TAG = "DocSnippets";
        StorageReference storageReference;

        public PostAdapter2(Query mQuery) {
            super(mQuery);
        }

        public interface OnPostSelectedListener {

            void onRestaurantSelected(DocumentSnapshot post);

        }

        private OnPostSelectedListener mListener;

        public PostAdapter2(Query query, OnPostSelectedListener listener) {
            super(query);
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_list_layout, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.bind(getSnapshot(position), mListener);
        }

        static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


            View mView;

            private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
            private String mUserId;


            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
            }

            public void bind(final DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                             final OnPostSelectedListener listener) {
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                mUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


                PostsModel post = snapshot.toObject(PostsModel.class);
                Resources resources = itemView.getResources();

                textViewPostUsername.setText(post.getPost_author_username());

                final String documentId;
                documentId = snapshot.getId();
               //final String documentId = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();
                final String postAuthorName = post.getPost_author_username();
                final String postAuthorid     = post.getPost_author_id();





            }
        }
    }
```

HomeFragment Class (where the above adapter is implemented)

```
    mQuery = PostsRef.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit( 50 );


    mParent =view.findViewById(R.id.relative_home);


    if (mQuery == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "No query, not initializing RecyclerView");
    }



    adapter = new PostAdapter2(mQuery) {

        @Override
        protected void onDataChanged() {
            // Show/hide content if the query returns empty.
            if (getItemCount() == 0) {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            // Show a snackbar on errors
            //Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
            ///      "Error: check logs for info.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(c));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Read official documentation here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md#using-the-firestorepagingadapter

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo the above code is working properly with filters applied during runtime. I want to implement Pagination using FirestorePagingAdapter or any other means. If you want more code I will provide.

Comment: @xaif I gone through the link you shared, which I have already tried but no good yet. I just unable to implement the pagination as it changes the structure for the filter implementation, is there anything more which you can share with  me?

Comment: @AlexMamo I will be very grateful if you help me

Comment: @ FrankvanPuffelen  can you help me in this case, I have gone through a lot of documentation but no success yet